# How to successfully implement Multiprocessing Lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have been following the example [synchronization-between-processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) from the multiprocessing document. The script is as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

When running this on virtual studio code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 110, in __setstate__
    self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock._rebuild(*state)
```

However, when I run the `threading` version, I get:

```
#from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from threading import Thread, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    try:
        print('hello world', i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Thread(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()

#
hello world 0
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 4
hello world 5
hello world 6
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 9
```

Why am I getting an error from the first example?

Comment: are you sure that's the entire error traceback? Is it an OSError? RuntimeError? etc? Try running your code in a normal terminal window (not your IDE). The code itself is fine.

Comment: As an aside, your function `f` can be simplified to: `with l: print('hello world', i)`